# Why my first page appears like this in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I wrote my code but I can't figure out why my first page appears like this:

[image]

[image]

enter code here
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func onAddTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController( title: "Post Something", message: "what would you like to post?",preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField{(textField) in textField.placeholder = "Enter Message here"}

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel" , style: .cancel, handler:nil)
    let post = UIAlertAction(title: "Post", style: .default){
        _ in guard let text = alert.textFields?.first?.text else{return}
        print(text)
    }
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    alert.addAction(post)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



}
```

Comment: Please add the source code you wrote. Of course as text!

Comment: I cant add my code here the limit is 600 character

Comment: Add it in your post, not in a comment. You can edit your post by clicking the `edit`-link!

Comment: you can look at the code now

Comment: Please post it as text, not as an image!

Answer (score 0):

The default base app in Xcode uses `Main.storyboard` for an entry point. `Main.storyboard` has one view controller that shows Hello World as the initial view controller by default. If you wrote your own view controller, you can go to the identity inspector in the top right of the storyboard editor and change ViewController.swift to the file where your view controller code is written.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using SwiftUI, so you have the "Hello World" inside ContentView. In order to use Storyboards and UIKit you need to create a project and select the .storyboard option.

[image]

Comment: What suppose to be in LaunchScreen.storyboard??

Comment: That always happen to me just when I use TableView

Comment: LaunchScreen should be empty. Can you take a screenshot of your Main.storyboard?

Comment: Yes I uploaded the picture

Comment: Thats great , can u tell me how did u reach there?

Answer (score 0):

You may not set initial view controller in storyboard. Please make sure you have set initial view controller

[image]